# How to put button abover other and at the bottom android?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I would like to know how to put my three buttons at the bottom in the right order.
Actually the three buttons are aligned but at the top.

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
tools:context="com.example.siansa.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:text="@string/connexion"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/inscription"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gold"
    android:text="@string/guest"
               android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this in your XML?

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button"
android:layout_below="@+id/button"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
```

**Edit:**

Or try:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: I'm sorry i explained badly, the three buttons are already in this order :

BUTTON1 , next line , BUTTON2, next line, BUTTON3

But I want them at the bottom of the view

Comment: That will only work in a RelativeLayout.  You might want to edit your answer?

Comment: Ok so i went to relative, the button are the same but when i move my top button to the bottom , I can't see the 2 other button because they are out of the view

Comment: You still use one of these two layouts? android:layout_above="@+id/button"
android:layout_below="@+id/button"

Comment: I add some more options to try, if it works please accept this answer. Thanks